# Grails 4 and Jib - Grails Views not included in Docker image

Tags: grails, jib

I created a new Grails 4.0.3 web app and added the Jib Gradle plugin to it. I can create the docker image using `gradle jibBuildTar`, load it into docker, and run it. Unfortunately, GSPs don't seem to get included in the image, so I run into the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

If I have UrlMappings go to a controller that renders text, the text renders just fine, so the app seems to be working except for the views.

In the build folder, I don't see `gsp-classes`, and when running jib, I don't see anything about the asset pipeline in the terminal.

What can I do to get jib to integrate with the asset pipline/grails views?

Comment: Jib dev here: I don't know anything about Grail, but it's possible that an Grail app isn't just what Jib can natively containerize at the moment. I'm actually interested in learning the Grail app structure and exploring potential ways for Jib to support Grail. If you can provide us with a sample app, could you file a new issue on [Jib GitHub repo](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/new)?

Comment: @ChanseokOh I’ll try and get you that soon as it would be great to use jib in this project. In the meantime, it turns out that Grails has a guide on how to integrate with Docker (manually at the bottom, but uses a prepareDocker task mentioned earlier on the page): https://guides.grails.org/grails-as-docker-container/guide/index.html.

Comment: @ChanseokOh I put in an issue here: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/2569. Thank you for, at the very least, the interest.